# Tterm 'react-native' is not recognized when running react-native run android

Tags: react-native

I need help in building my react-native project. I have tried react-native run-android but I get the following error:

```
react-native : The term 'react-native' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ react-native run android
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (react-native:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Post the command you are using and the source.

Answer (score 3):

Iyayi Kelvin

You will need Node, the React Native command line interface, a JDK, and Android Studio.

I assumed you have, 
Development OS: Linux, Target OS: Android

**Node**
https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

**The React Native CLI**

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

**Java Development Kit**
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

**Android development environment**
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

**Watchman (optional)**
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html#buildinstall

**Creating a new application**

```
$ react-native init AwesomeProject

$ cd AwesomeProject

$ react-native run-android
```

Note : 
if you get an error as follow:
`"unable to load scripts from assets 'index.android.bundle' on real device"`

Then,
(If not created then) create dir as `android/app/src/main/assets`

### Old react native version below < 0.46

```
$ react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

or

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

Then,

```
$ react-native run-android
```

Comment: Many thanks...this helped "npm install -g react-native-cli". It installed all dependecies. I greatly appreciate your support.

Comment: Old react native version below < 0.46
In your solve, both are same.

Answer (score 2):

run this command

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

after that just add your npm path to your **system variables** in environment variables

```
C:\Users\YOUR USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm
```